# How to wait till response come from rest API with $resource POST method request in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

> **Issue:** This is my Angularjs code where I have called POST method with the token. It takes some time to give the response from backend and thus Angularjs code is considering the response value as null and starting further execution.
>   Please make me correct if I am going wrong.
>
> **Expected result:** AngularJS call should wait for the response from backend insted of executing further code.

```
this.csrfHeaderName_ = kdCsrfTokenHeader;
this.tokenService_ = kdCsrfTokenService;
let csrfTokenPromise = this.tokenService_.getTokenForAction('shiftm');
let deferred = $q.defer();
csrfTokenPromise.then(
  (csrfToken) => {
    let resource = $resource('api/v1/shiftm', {}, {
      save: {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          [this.csrfHeaderName_]: csrfToken, //Token
        },
      },
    });
    resource.save(
      shiftmData, (response) => {
        if (response.length !== 0 && response.length === 0) {
          console.log("Response Length is Nonzero");
          console.log("shiftmData==>",response);
        }
        else {
          console.log("Response Length is zero");
        }
        deferred.resolve('request successful');
      },
     (err) => {
        deferred.reject(err);
      });
      },
  (err) => {
    deferred.reject(err);
  });
return deferred.promise;
```

Comment: Hello. **This is the point of using deferred promise**. I think you probably misunderstood something about this. I suggest you to take a look to the documentation : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Comment: Where and how is the function is being called inside the controller where you want to wait for the completion of execution. Please share that code as well. I would like to see its implementation

Comment: @MickaëlB and @ Shashank Vivek thanks for taking a look, actually I am new in Angularjs. The above angularjs code hits my backend module which has been developed in Go language. The backend code is working properly. As it is taking more time to send the response. I am getting NULL values in my frontend code. Please correct me if I am doing wrong.